# How can i send a folders name to a function by clicking on it in C++

Tags: c++, file-io

I've hit a metaphorical roadblock. I have got a program which loads text files when you enter their name. But i would like to take 1 step further, here is what I currently have:

```
string name;  
ifstream save;    
cout<<"\nPlease choose a save file: ";  
cin>>name;  
save.open(string(name+".txt").c_str());
```

and what I would like is when the program reaches this point, it opens Windows Explorer, you then click on the file, and that sends the filename to `ifstream.open()`.
I'm not sure if its possible, but I'm willing to put any amount of effort into it to make it work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

PS: if any of thats confusing just say and ill try to clear it up

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming by Explorer you mean Windows' open file dialog. Use the [GetOpenFileName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646927%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. It's a WINAPI function.

It's defined in windows.h, so you'll need to include it (add `#include <windows.h>` to your program).

Comment: Wow that was fast! Thanks for the help, ill try it